# CCActionCallBlock usage in Cocos2d Swift

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

I used below cocos2d-swift code, giving 1 error. See below image.

```
var calBck  = CCActionCallBlock.actionWithBlock({
                self.showGlassEffect()
        }) as CCActionCallBlock
var seq = CCActionSequence.actions(move, delay, calBck, nil) as CCActionSequence
```

[image]

How to use CCActionCallBlock in Cocos2d Swift ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var seq = CCActionSequence.actionWithArray(arr) as CCActionSequence
```